# Why isn't django development server finding my static files

Tags: django

I'm really confused about this. I've got a django site set up and my settings are all correct, but when I run my server it doesn't find the files. See below for the necessary code.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments',
    'best_schools',
    'debug_toolbar',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]
# --snip--
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '/static/'
```

directory structure:

```
jonathan at k-nine ~/Sites/tbs_django (master tbs_django) [02:04 pm]
 -> ls ./
best_schools/  db.sqlite3  license.txt  manage.py*  README.md  requirements.txt  static/  tbs/  templates/
```

ipython console:

```
In [1]: from tbs import settings

In [2]: settings.STATIC_ROOT
Out[2]: '/home/jonathan/Sites/tbs_django/static/'

In [3]: settings.STATIC_URL
Out[3]: '/static/'
```

output of `manage.py findstatic` doesn't even see my static directory:

```
jonathan at k-nine ~/Sites/tbs_django (master tbs_django) [02:06 pm]
 -> manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 custom-admin.css
/home/jonathan/Sites/tbs_django/manage.py
No matching file found for 'custom-admin.css'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /home/jonathan/.virtualenvs/django-tbs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /home/jonathan/.virtualenvs/django-tbs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/static
```

I have this in my urls.py: `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

The weird thing is that when I run `manage.py runserver --nostatic` it works perfectly. Why does django not find my static files? I'm running Django 1.10.2.

Comment: Where are your static files located? They should be in a static/ directory in your app, and be moved to the STATIC_ROOT only in production (by manage.py collectstatic).

Comment: Do the static files of the admin work?

Comment: Admin works great. Static files are all located in the static/ directory shown in the output above. I'm playing around with moving the static files around to see if I can get django to see them

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Comment: You figured it out. I had my static files in the wrong place. Thanks. When you get the answer written I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the idea is that static files *belong to an app*, and are located in that app's directory in `static/`. That's how Django's own apps work, and that's why the admin works.

The static files for the best_schools app, for instance, should be in

```
'/home/jonathan/Sites/tbs_django/best_schools/static/best_schools/'
```

(yes, that's twice `best_schools`). You should have to put anything in urls.py for runserver to find them.

Then when you go to production and have the files be served by some web server other than Django, you run `python manage.py collectstatic`, that searches through all the INSTALLED_APPS and copies the files to the configured STATIC_ROOT, that you server with the web server.

Answer (score 0):

try to add those lines in urls.py and use collectstatic

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`python manage.py collectstatic`